# Reuse playbook and pass host from master playbook

Tags: ansible

I have `select.yml` with prompts for IP and `machine_id.yml` which should be included from `select.yml` and should takes host from `select.yml`. I've tried many configurations without success.

How to reuse `machine_id.yml` and inject host into it?

select.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: target_host
    prompt: "[M] please enter the target host IP"
    private: no
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ target_host }}"
        groups: dynamic_hosts
    - import_playbook: machine_id.yml
```

machine_id.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: target_host
    prompt: please enter the target host IP
    private: no
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ target_host }}"
        groups: dynamic_hosts

- hosts: "{{ dynamic_hosts }}"
  vars:  
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Reset machine-id
      shell: rm /etc/machine-id && rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id && dbus-uuidgen --ensure=/etc/machine-id && dbus-uuidgen --ensure
      args:
        warn: no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right way. `- import_playbook: machine_id.yml` must be on the level of `- hosts:`

Here is an example which worked for me:

select.yaml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: target_host
    prompt: "[M] please enter the target host IP"
    private: no
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ target_host }}"
        groups: dynamic_hosts
    - debug: var=groups
- import_playbook: machine_id.yaml
```

machine_id.yaml:

```
- hosts: dynamic_hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

Can you give it a try? If it's not working, please let us know your error.

Comment: Yes. That was that. Thanks.